# Delta hedge a long option using a short option

Tags: options, delta-hedging

If I long a call option of 1 mio USD/SGD for example, I understand that at strike price (ATM), delta is approximately +0.5.

To approximately hedge this delta, I also understand we can short 0.5 mio of the underlying USD/SGD spot.

What I don't understand is **how is the delta hedged when we short a call option of 2 mio USD/SGD instead**?

Comment: Can you elaborate? If 1 call option is 0.5 delta, then two call options are 1.0 delta and you would need 1.0 of the underlying to hedge it (although this hedge ratio will, as usual, change)